# Does the additive structure of a ring of S-integers detect the ring structure?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-number-theory, abelian-groups

Suppose that $K$ and $L$ are number fields with rings of integers $\mathcal O_K$ and $\mathcal O_L$. Let $S$ and $T$ be finite sets of absolute values containing all archimedean valuations of $K$ and $L$, respectively.

As noted in the comments - recall that the ring of S-integers in $K$ is $$O_{K,S}:=\{x\in K\colon |x|_v \leq 1\;\mathrm{for \;all}\;v\not\in S\}$$

Suppose now that we have an **additive** isomorphism $$\mathcal O_{K,S}\cong\mathcal O_{L,T}$$

> **Question:** Does it follow that $K=L$ and $S=T$ ?

To avoid trivialities (to avoid for example $O_{K,S}\cong \mathbb Z^n$) we assume that the abelian groups in question are **indecomposable**.

Comment: What is $\mathcal O_{K,S}$?  Do you mean $$\{ x \in K : |x|_v \leq 1 \textrm{ for all } v \not\in S \}$$

Comment: Also, aren't indecomposable abelian groups just $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @D_S Yes, that is what I mean. Sorry if it was not clear. Those groups are the only _finitely generated_ indecomposable abelian groups. Consider $\mathbb Q$ for a non f.g. example.

Comment: Do you allow the two RINGS to be NOT isomorphic ?

Comment: Good point- I suppose I assumed that if the rings are not isomorphic then either $K\not= L$ or $S\not=T$. If you have a counterexample to that I'd be interested.

Comment: I don't understand your requirement of indecomposability. Let K be a number field of degree n. Then the ring of S-integers O_K,S is but the localisation of the ring of integers O_K w.r.t. to the multiplicative set consisting of ideals with support away from S. But such localization of a noetherian domain is still noetherian (P. Samuel, chap.5, §5.1). It follows easily that O_K,S is Z-free of rank n (it contains a basis which is obtained from a Q-basis of K by multiplying the basis-vectors by the non-S-part of a common denominator).

Comment: Consider the trivial case of the rational integers $\mathbb Z\subseteq\mathbb Q$: inverting a prime $p$ gives the Noetherian domain $\mathbb Z[1/p]$ which is not finitely generated as an abelian group.

Comment: Ah! I see : the localized ring is a noetherian RING .